# Message indicator after specific time?

Tags: software-recommendation, scripts, tools

Is there any tool this can indicate message after each 30 minutes of uptime ?

actually I  spend too many time on computer so i want tool which indicate message after every 30 minutes.

like, when uptime is **30 minutes** I want sound notification and  message  like :- "**You have on laptop since 30 minutes turn  off and study"**.

same for next 30 minutes till 2 hours.
ie :

**30 minutes**

**1 hour**

**1:30 hours**

2:**00 hours**

Is this possible ? if yes how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a script with following containt

```
#!/bin/bash

first_u=$(awk  '{printf "%.0f" , $0/60;}' /proc/uptime)
while true
do
  uptime_m=$(awk  '{printf "%.0f" , $0/60;}' /proc/uptime)
  (( time_dif=$uptime_m - $first_u ))


 if [  $time_dif -eq 30 ]; then
   notify-send "You have on laptop since 30 minutes"
   sleep 1800
    notify-send "You have on laptop since 1 hour"
   sleep 1800
    notify-send "You have on laptop since 1:30 hour"
   sleep 1800
    notify-send "You have on laptop since 2 hour"
   break
 fi
 sleep 50
done
```

Save it and make it executable using

```
chmod a+x <script_name>
```

Now run it

```
 ./<script_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1**   Try **alarm-clock-applet**

```
sudo apt-get install alarm-clock-applet
```

**2** Also **Gnome Clock** has a countdown feature. But it has to be set manually every time.

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome-clocks
```